# Pattern.format(date) vs Date.fomat(Pattern)?

Tags: java, date, datetime, format, datetimeformatter

I came to know that DateTimeFormatter has two implementation for formatting the date.

1. Pattern.format(date)
2. Date.format(pattern)

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter pattern = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
        String dateFormatText = date.format(pattern);
        String patternFormatText = pattern.format(date); 
        System.out.println(dateFormatText);
        System.out.println(patternFormatText);
   }
   ```

Both the SysOut prints the same value.

The Oracle docs examples uses Date.format method, whereas I can see many tech blogs using the Pattern.format method.

Can anyone explain me what is the difference and which is best to use?

Source Code Demo : [Here](https://onlinegdb.com/WouUsPj2k)

Comment: At least in my version of the JDK, `date.format(pattern)` just calls `pattern.format(date)` after checking if `pattern` is null, so I think it's just a matter of "which way of expressing this idea makes more sense to you?" In your mind, is it that formatters format dates, or is it that dates can format themselves _using a formatter_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can anyone explain me what is the difference?

There is no significant difference.

The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#format-java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter-) for `LocalDateTime.format` says:

> `public String format(DateTimeFormatter formatter)`
>
> Formats this date-time using the specified formatter.
>
> This date-time will be passed to the formatter to produce a string.

In other words, `LocalDateTime.format` calls `DateTimeFormatter.format`.

---

> ... and which is best to use?

Neither is "best".

It is up to you decide which form *expresses your intention* more clearly.  Do you want to say:

- "`LocalDateTime`: format yourself with this formatter", or
- "`DateTimeFormatter`: format this temporal value".

Answer (score 2):

Though opinion-based I will try an answer.

As Stephen C has already documented, the two forms are equivalent.

Which is best? As so often in programming the answer is: It‘s best to write what will be least surprising to those reading your code.

So what will be least surprising? I am sure that the answer varies. Your organization will — consciously or unconsciously — build a tradition for what you are doing, and the least surprising will be to follow that tradition.

### Points of each option

I’d also like to take a look at some thinkable reasons why both options have crept into java.time. This may give us some further thoughts on advantages of one or the other.

And since I don’t do mind reading, it’s guesswork. I think that the form `date.format(formatter)` was formed with inspiration from at least two sides:

1. It’s parallel to `date.toString()`, which with java.time we also often use for formatting a date-time object to a string. In Joda-Time, the predecessor of java.time, we even had the same method name: `date.toString(formatter)`.
2. It’s somehow parallel to `DateType.parse(string, formatter)`, which is what we use for the opposite operation, converting the string to a date-time object. For example `LocalDate.parse("08/04/2021", pattern)`. This form in turn is necessary with the design of java.time. `formatter.parse(string)` wouldn’t know whether to parse into a `LocalDate`, an `Instant`, a `ZonedDateTime` or one of the many other date-time types of java.time. (The form `pattern.parse("08/04/2021", LocalDate::from)` exists as an alternative, though, and is sometimes necessary, but not often used.)

And I may be missing something, but one reason why many tech blogs use `formatter.format(date)` is inspiration from the now obsolete `SimpleDateFormat` that consistently used `format.format(date)`. I cannot completely escape the thought that maybe those bloggers have not fully gone into the java.time way of thinking.

Comment: That's quite a big analysis !! Thank you